# Fade transition between two absolute divs with different heights

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two `article` tags positioned as absolute and I want to transition between them using a fade effect.

I am using `opacity` and `z-index` to achieve this.

The problem I am having is that when the article behind the active one has content that makes it higher than the one in front when the page scrolls it becomes visible, the only way to avoid that is to use `display: none` or `overflow: hidden` but this makes the page either not fadable or not scrollable.

I got this:

```js
// When clicking on a next button change the active class
document.querySelector('#next').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active')
  document.querySelector('#about').classList.add('active')
})
```

```css
html, body, main {
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

body {
 background: pink;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}


.content {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

article {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: no-repeat fixed bottom / cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease;
  background-color: #fff;
}

article.active {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<body>
<main>

  <article id='intro' class='active'>
    <div class='content'>
      <div class='container'>
        This is the front page
        
        <button id='next'>Next</button>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article id='about'>
    <div class='content'>
      <div class='container'>
         This is the page behind the front that I cannot hide cause its content makes it higher
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br><br><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article> 
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see the body `background-color: pink` when scrolling caused by the height of the about article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to combine changing two classes. For example, 'active' class sets the height of `article`, and `visible` class makes `article` visible:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.next').forEach( btn => btn.onclick = () => changeArticle('next') )
document.querySelectorAll('.prev').forEach( btn => btn.onclick = () => changeArticle('prev') )

function changeArticle(direction) {
  const activeArticle = document.querySelector('.active');
  const elementSibling = direction === 'next' ? 'nextElementSibling' : 'previousElementSibling';
  const nextArticle = activeArticle[elementSibling];
  activeArticle.classList.remove('visible');
  nextArticle.classList.add('visible');
  /* transition-duration delay */
  setTimeout(() => {
    activeArticle.classList.remove('active')
    nextArticle.classList.add('active');
  }, 400);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: pink;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

article {
  inset: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity .4s, visibility .4s;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: max-content;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

article:not(.active) {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

article:not(.visible) {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#intro {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#about {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.content {
  width: min(500px, 100%);
  padding: 40px 20px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article id="intro" class="active visible">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="container">
        This is the front page
        <button class="next">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article id="about">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="container">
        <button class="prev">Prev</button>
        This is the page behind the front that I cannot hide cause its content makes it higher
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br><br><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article> 
</main>
```

---

Or you can to set all `.article` to the highest `height`. Something like this:

```js
setArticlesHeight()
window.onresize = setArticlesHeight;

function setArticlesHeight(){
  let largeHeight = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll('article').forEach( el => el.style.removeProperty('height') );
  document.querySelectorAll('article').forEach(el => {
    if ( el.scrollHeight > largeHeight ) {
      largeHeight = el.scrollHeight;
    }
  })
  document.querySelectorAll('article').forEach(el => el.style.height = largeHeight + 'px');
}

document.querySelectorAll('.next').forEach( btn => btn.onclick = () => goToArticle('next') )

document.querySelectorAll('.prev').forEach( btn => btn.onclick = () => goToArticle('prev') )

function goToArticle(direction) {
  const activeArticle = document.querySelector('.active');
  document.querySelectorAll('article').forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
  if(direction === 'next') {
    activeArticle.nextElementSibling.classList.add('active');
  }
  if(direction === 'prev') {
    activeArticle.previousElementSibling.classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: pink;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

article {
  inset: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity .4s, visibility .4s;
}

article:not(.active) {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#intro {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#about {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article id="intro" class="active">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="container">
        This is the front page
        <button class="next">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article id="about">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="container">
        <button class="prev">Prev</button>
        This is the page behind the front that I cannot hide cause its content makes it higher
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br><br><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article> 
</main>
```

Comment: I don't see what you are writing about. When scrolling, there is only the color of the `article.active`.

Comment: My bad, it was the wrong implementation of the JS, it's working fine for me now. Thanks!

Comment: Even thou this kind of fixes the problem, it really is not practical to have the active screen to be as tall as the one behind, as it might be a completly different screen

Comment: You are probably right. Updated my answer.

Comment: Only one thing tou, now the content is not centered with display grid

Comment: Ok, fixed......

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253910/discussion-between-imhvost-and-alvaro).

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Looks like it can be solved using `100vh` for the heights</strike>

Based on my comment: this is what I meant with 'simplify':

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  if (evt.target.closest(`button`)) {
    const nxt = evt.target.closest(`button`).dataset.next;
    document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
    return document.querySelector(nxt).classList.add('active');
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}

/* for creating space in demo */
article div p {
  min-height: 1.2rem;
}

article {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  left: 50%;
  height: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: rgb(245, 191, 200);
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

article div {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 75%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: rgb(245, 191, 200);
  transition: opacity, background-color 0.5s ease;
}

article.active {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

article.active div {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <article class="active" id="intro">
    <div>
      This is the front page
      <button data-next="#about">Next</button>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article id="about">
    <div>
      This is the page behind the front that I cannot 
      hide cause its content makes it higher
      <button data-next="#intro">Previous</button>
      <p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p>
      <p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p>
       <p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p>
       <p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p><p></p>
       <p></p><p></p><p></p>
       <p>THE LAST PARAGRAPH</p>
    </div>
  </article>
</main>
```

Comment: If you replace the `<p>` for the actual `<br>` you will see it happens on yours too. The `p` does not increase the height on the article but `br` does, which reflects better the problem I have seens there are no empty `p` on the about article but content that adds height

Comment: Well, in that case ... I can't find enougth time to figure out a solid solution, sorry! One of the things that helps me often is to simplify the html and css as much as possible.

Comment: Yes, the compromise I have made is removing the fade effect with a `display: none`.